# query inside with eloquent

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-blade

image address has location and total number of users.

```
    Users::with(['address'=>function($query){
    $query->where('location', 'NAXAL');
    $query->order By('total');
    }])->get();
```

this query will return all the users and on relation whose query did not match will be null .I want to pull only those users which do not null value on relation and order By accordingly.

Comment: have you tried [`whereHas`](https://laravel.com/api/6.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_whereHas)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use whereHas condition

```
Users::whereHas('address', function($query){
$query->where('location', 'NAXAL');
$query->order By('total');
})->get();
```

Comment: thanks man. how could i forget there was whereHas also

Comment: but orderBy still not working

Comment: Order By will not work inside the above query. You can try left join in eloquent it will work with orderBy

Users::join('address', 'condition', 'left')->orderBy('address.total')->where('address.location', 'NAXAL')->get();